# При запуске локального сервера не выполняются изменения в коде

Tags: javascript, html, css, openserver, localhost

Использую OSPanel я перекидывала файл заново в папку domains, ничего не меняется. Когда запускаю код в яндексе все хорошо, а в гугл никаких изменений.

Можно ли изменить браузер запуска локального сервера?

Comment: Детализируйте свой вопрос. Что значит код в яндексе? Какой файл перекидываете, что открываете и так далее

Comment: как минимум может быть надо чистить кэш хрома.............а лучше при разработке отключить... изменить браузер не ясно когда...... ты в любой момент можешь открыть **любой браузер** и там смотреть.......а если открываешь из IDE - то там тоже выбор есть

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открываете настройки OSPanel, заходишь во вкладку меню, ставишь галочку на "Открывать веб-страницы в указанном браузере", выбираете браузер. Файл с которым вы работаете должен находиться в папке domains, и веб страницу вы должны открывать "Мои проекты > файл с которым вы работаете". Кстати бывает так что когда перекидываешь папку с которым вы работаете, в папку domains, она туда копируется, и допустим вы работаете в VScode с папкой с рабочего стола, а надо именно тот что в папке открыть. При каждом изменении нужно обновлять страницу со сбросом кэша, в хром это сочетание клавиш "Ctrl+F5". И если вдруг вы работает с json-server, он у вас тоже должен быть запущен.